# How can I show RSA-OAEP is not IND-CCA secure if G always outputs 0 (i.e. there is no hash function)?

Tags: rsa, chosen-ciphertext-attack

Here is what I understand the algorithm to be:

Let $G, H$ be one-way functions, where G outputs the 0 string.

- Select a random $$-bit integer $$.
- Pad out $$ with $0$s to length $=||−.$
- Compute $=()⊕_{}$ (i.e. $X = _{}$)
- Compute $=⊕()$
- Return $||$

- Compute $r = Y \oplus H(X)$
- Compute $m_{padded} = X \oplus G(r)$ (i.e. $m_{padded} = X$)
- Strip off the $0$s from $X = _{}$ to recover $$

**IND-CCA Game**

The IND-CCA game in this case is as follows:

- The adversary selects two messages $_0,_1$ and submits them to a decryption oracle $O$.
- The decryption oracle samples $∈\{0,1\}$ and computes $*= \textrm{RSA-OAEP}(_)$.
- The adversary is free to perform more decryptions, except for the one condition that $O(c∗)$ will return $⊥$.
- To conclude, the adversary must guess $$ corresponding to the message that was encrypted.

**Work towards showing that algorithm is not IND-CCA secure**

The adversary need only recover $X$ from $c$, where $c = \textrm{RSA_OAEP}(m_b) = \textrm{RSA}(X||Y)$. Very basic question, but is $m_b \in \{b||m_1, b||m_2\}$? If so, then the adversary would know that $X||Y$ differs by $|X|$ significant digits depending on the value of $b$. However, $Y$ will always differ since $b$ is random, so $c = \textrm{RSA}(X||Y)$ will also always differ.

Unsure of where to go from here, any help would be much appreciated!

The adversary wants to output either the plaintext or $\bot$. For RSA-OAEP, $⊥$ is output when either the adversary tries to decrypt $c*$, or if the first half of the padding is not the 0 string then the decryption fails. Could we try multiplying $m_0 = 0...0$ and $m_1 =$ random with $2^e$ mod $N$?

Comment: Thanks for the help and the welcome! I reintroduced $G$ to my question to make what I'm asking clearer - initially I just removed $G$ from the algorithm for brevity. However, I am not sure that the same plaintext will encrypt to the same ciphertext, given that $m$ will encode to $X||Y$ rather than just $X$. Also, for the basic question, if $m_b$ is just one digit, does it need to be padded for length requirements?

Comment: Independently of the defective $G$, the question's OAEP is not [RSAES-OAEP](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=16) as practiced, which includes consistency check in the _Decode_ procedure. Combined with the defective $G$ (RSAES-OAEP's MGF), that allows an attack in the IND-CCA2 game (not IND-CCA1). Hint:  what if having received a ciphertext $C_b$ for $m_b$ from the encryption oracle, the adversary submits $N−C_b$ to the decryption oracle (which IND-CCA2 essentially allows)?

Comment: Independently of the above comment: the defective $G$ allows the adversary to choose values of $m_b$ that consistently make $X\mathbin\|Y$ relatively small, and that makes the RSA primitive less resilient, especially for low $e$ and narrow $H$. But that attack is not specific to [IND-CCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#Indistinguishability_under_chosen_ciphertext_attack/adaptive_chosen_ciphertext_attack_(IND-CCA1,_IND-CCA2)), thus probably this is not what the problem's author has in mind.

Comment: $N - C_b$ undergoes RSA decoding, $(N - C_b)^d$ mod $N = (-C_b)^d$ mod $N$ = $\pm m_b$ mod $N$, since ${C_b}^d$ mod $N$ decrypts to $m_b$ by definition of its encryption. So it decrypts to either $N - m_b$ or $m_b$ depending on whether $d$ is even?

Comment: $d$ is always odd in RSA. Somewhat you think that $m_b={C_b}^d\bmod N$, and but that has no reason to hold. Check more carefully how encryption works: it applies the encoding, then applies raw RSA encryption.

Comment: Right, we have $X||Y = {C_b}^d\mod N$, and $X = m_b$. I had that in the back of my mind but wasn't sure how to work it in. So the RSA decrypts to $N - X||Y$, and we can recover $m_b$ from the binary difference of the first half of $N$ and $X$? Or am I still totally on the wrong track?

Comment: Correct, except that you are assimilating $m_b$ to $m_{b\text{ padded}}$ (and BTW my bets are on $\ell=\mathbin\|N\mathbin\|-\mathbin\|k\mathbin\|$ rather than what the question states), and independently "we can recover $m_b$" is even so slightly overoptimistic: we can do this with overwhelming probability, but (unless I err) some exception; or we can recognize which $m_b$ that is, with certainty, for proper choice of the $m_b$ (in either case, that's still more than needed to win the IND-CCA2 game with sizable advantage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $b$ is random

Yes, but it is random in the set $\{0,1\}$. $b$ reflects the coin toss made by the decryption oracle / challenger in the IND-CCA game to decide if s/he encrypts $m_0$ or $m_1$ at the second bullet.

> Does $m_b \in \{b\mathbin\|m_1,\ b\mathbin\|m_2\}$ ?

No in general, and that holds even if we fix the indices to be in $\{0,1\}$ rather than $\{1,2\}$. The intended meaning of $m_b$ is:
$$m_b=\begin{cases}m_0&\text{if }b=0\\m_1&\text{if }b=1\\\end{cases}$$
otherwise said, $b=0\implies m_b=m_0$, and $b=1\implies m_b=m_1$. Thus $m_b \in \{m_0, m_1\}$ with no concatenation involved. Note: the IND-CCA game allows to choose the two messages $m_0$ and $m_1$ equal, but that's a silly move.

Comment: I see, I was thinking of $b \in \{0,1\}$ as being part of the encryption, rather than relating to the subscript of the two messages $m_0$, $m_1$ generated by the adversary. Thank you!